# How to return just distinct values from json.agg() function

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following query

```
select json_agg(t) from (
select  json_build_object(
'field_1',a.field_1,
'field_2',a.field_2,
'field_4',json_agg(json_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)),
'field_9',json_agg(json_build_object('id',i.optionid,'data',i.option))
 ) as data

from schema_1.tbl_342 a
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_329_field_10 b on a.id=b.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_customid c on b.tbl_329_id=c.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23_join d on c.id=d.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23 e on d.optionid = e.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_312_field_4 f on a.id=f.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_312_customid g on f.tbl_312_id = g.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9_join h on h.id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9 i on i.optionid=h.optionid   
group by a.field_1,a.field_2
) t
```

This results in the following `JSON` format

```
   [
  {
  "data":{
     "field_1":"John",
     "field_2":null,
     "field_4":[
        {
           "id":null,
           "data":null
        }
     ],
     "field_9":[
        {
           "id":2,
           "data":"Green"
        }
     ]
  }
 },
 {
  "data":{
     "field_1":"Jackson",
     "field_2":null,
     "field_4":[
        {
           "id":2,
           "data":"Marketing Manager M1004"
        },
        {
           "id":4,
           "data":"Senior Javascript Engineer"
        },
        {
           "id":5,
           "data":"Recruiter"
        }
     ],
     "field_9":[
        {
           "id":3,
           "data":"Red"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "data":"Red"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "data":"Red"
        }
     ]
  }
 },
  {
    "data":{
     "field_1":"Jacob",
     "field_2":null,
     "field_4":[
        {
           "id":null,
           "data":null
        }
     ],
     "field_9":[
        {
           "id":null,
           "data":null
        }
     ]
  }
 },
 {
  "data":{
     "field_1":"Todd",
     "field_2":null,
     "field_4":[
        {
           "id":null,
           "data":null
        }
     ],
     "field_9":[
        {
           "id":4,
           "data":"Yellow"
        }
     ]
  }
 },
 {
  "data":{
     "field_1":"Billy",
     "field_2":null,
     "field_4":[
        {
           "id":5,
           "data":"Recruiter"
        }
     ],
     "field_9":[
        {
           "id":1,
           "data":"Blue"
        }
     ]
   }
 }
 ]
```

In this example, I'm trying to fix two things.

1.Removing the `data` node element. I'd like to have the objects start at root, not in `Data`

2.Notice in the second node. The `field_4` has 3 elements, but `field_9` has a single `red` value in DB. Here it's repeating the duplicate values, must be matching the number of returned records from `field_4`

How can I get just distinct values from this aggregate?
I've tried

```
 'field_4',distinct json_agg(json_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)),
```

and other forms like that, but it doesn't like the syntax.
FYI, I'm using PostgreSQL 11

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers and solution for your problem will be as below:

**Problem 1** - You are using `json_agg(t)` to generate the final `JSON` data which will pick all column names or alias as key for `JSON` and aggregate it. So here you should use `array_to_json(array_agg(t.data))`. `array_agg` will convert the result of subquery in array and then array_to_json will convert the final array to `JSON`.

**Problem 2** - You want `distinct json object` in inner array. So `Distinct` can not be used with `json` data type because there is no `equality operator` available in `PostgreSQL` for `JSON` type. So you should use `JSONB`.

Considering your query mentioned in the question is working fine, try it :

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(t.data)) from (
select  jsonb_build_object(
'field_1',a.field_1,
'field_2',a.field_2,
'field_4',jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',g.id,'data',g.fullname)),
'field_9',jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('id',i.optionid,'data',i.option))
 ) as data

from schema_1.tbl_342 a
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_329_field_10 b on a.id=b.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_customid c on b.tbl_329_id=c.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23_join d on c.id=d.id
left join schema_1.tbl_329_field_23 e on d.optionid = e.optionid
left join schema_1.tbl_342_to_tbl_312_field_4 f on a.id=f.tbl_342_id
left join schema_1.tbl_312_customid g on f.tbl_312_id = g.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9_join h on h.id=a.id
left join schema_1.tbl_342_field_9 i on i.optionid=h.optionid   
group by a.field_1,a.field_2
) t
```

Comment: Thx! That solved the duplicate issue. The other issue is that, the top node is still "data". If I remove the "as data" it then shows top node as "json_object_build". what I want is for a node to have the format output like : {{"field_1": "Billy", "field_2": null, "field_4": [{"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}} . Currently it's {"data":{"field_1": "Billy", "field_2": null, "field_4": [{"id": 4, "data": "Senior Javascript Engineer"}

Comment: Ya it should be `array_to_json(array_agg(t.data))`. i have updated the answer

Comment: what's the result of this? do keys have name or is it 'f1':value?